# Why are `]` and `}` not metacharacters in Regex when ')' is?

Tags: regular-expressions

In [Regular Expressions Quick Start](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), it reads

> Twelve characters have special meanings in regular expressions: the backslash \, the caret ^, the dollar sign $, the period or dot ., the vertical bar or pipe symbol |, the question mark ?, the asterisk or star *, the plus sign +, the opening parenthesis (, the closing parenthesis ), the opening square bracket [, and the opening curly brace {. These special characters are often called "metacharacters". Most of them are errors when used alone.

In its specification, `()`, `[`,`{` are metacharacters whereas 'closing sqare bracket' and 'closing curly brace' are not.

Obviously,`[` and `{` unable to take an effect individually just like opening parenthesis `(` should partners `)`.

What's the reason that causes `]` and `}` failing to be selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a plain `]` in most regex engines and have it match a `]` in the input. This works because `]` on its own does not have special meaning.

Contrariwise, you *can't*  write a plain `[` to match a `[` in the input - the regex engine will complain that the brackets are unbalanced. This is probably why this text says that `[` is special and `]`isn't.

This seems unintuitive, but it's true. `]` has a special meaning **only within a character class**, and the special meaning is "terminate the class". This is just like `-`, which also has a special meaning **only within a character class** (the meaning is "create a range between the two neighbouring letters"). You wouldn't take this to mean that `-` *in general* is a metacharacter, and for the same reason `]` *in general* isn't a metacharacter.

If this seems weird, you're in good company, but it *is* the most logical way of looking at it. The reason it *looks* weird is that we're conditioned to consider [] () {} as matching pairs. (Compare the well-known "paradox" that `())(`is a palindrome, but `(())` *isn't*.)

Comment: It seems odd therefore that `)` doesn't fit into the same category as `}`, `]` and `-`. Is there a reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: @DavidArno You're right, most regex engines complain about a plain `)`. I never noticed that, probably because you rarely get tings starting with `)`. By my logic they should be able to deal with it, since it's unambiguously a normal character. I'm not sure why alternative-processing parsers tend to be pickier than the character-class parsers. Maybe it's because character-class logic is a lot simpler and more straightforward to implement?

Comment: I guess the reason behind it might have been an attempt to make regex expressions less error-prone (the irony of that statement isn't lost on me, BTW). `[]` and `{}` tend to only contain a few characters between them, so mistakes can be easier to spot. `()` can be nested and contain large sections of an expression, so spotting erroneous `)`'s could be more difficult. Pure speculation though.

Comment: Actually according to the POSIX spec: "The close-parenthesis shall be considered special in this context only if matched with a preceding open-parenthesis." But obviously some regex engines consider it a special character regardless. Anyway it's not like the spec came first - regex syntax has been around and morphed over time, and started as very simple, and wasn't consistent across engines... so parenthesis handling is probably different just due to that.